# Run query with huge comma separated inputs

Tags: sql, excel, toad

I have a list of 100,000 sequence numbers in excel. I want to check if these sequence number is available in a database table or not. What will be the easiest way? Any thing i can do with toad?

Comment: Forget writing a single query with 100,000 `OR` clauses.  Instead, load your numbers into a temporary table with `INSERT` or `COPY`, then use a join: `SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM existingtbl WHERE existingtbl.val = mytbl.val)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go with an in clause:

`SELECT * FROM table t1 WHERE col1 in (1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: the problem here is I cannot pass the 1Lakh records at once. Is there any easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are these numbers sequential? Or at least some are sequential? If so, sort them in excel and then use ranges like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1 
WHERE col1 BETWEEN 100 AND 1000
  AND col1 BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000
  AND ....
```

Of course, replace those numbers with your ranges.